# Can't resolve '.file.scss' in '../pages'

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have an Ionic 3 app and I decide to migrate to version 4. Some pages doesn't recognize the scss file from the typescript component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'car-id',
  templateUrl: 'car-id.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-id.page.scss']
})
```

The main aspect is that some pages work without problems.

This is the error

```
[ng]
[ng] ERROR in ./src/app/pages/car-id/car-id.page.ts
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './card-id.page.scss' in '..\src\app\pages\car-id'
```

How can I fix this? Ty

Comment: Did you mean to put `styleUrls: ['car-id.page.scss']`?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing great!!!

Since you have not put the entire folder structure but, I guess it is not able to find the files from the current directory.

Try using `./` as below (if it is in the same current folder): -

```
templateUrl: './card-id.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./card-id.page.scss']
```

Also, please check whether the below is a typo or a deliberate change by you: -

```
selector: 'car-id', // is the same name used in the parent component?
templateUrl: 'car-id.page.html', // did you mean card here?
styleUrls: ['card-id.page.scss'] // did u mean car here?
```

Hope I was able to solve your problem! Happy Coding!! Cheers!!!

Comment: Hi, for future reference, questions that are the result of a simple typo should be closed as off-topic rather than answered as they are likely to be counter productive for someone searching for a similar issue.

Comment: ty. I am so noob:))